# XSD: Allow element only if it does not have a certain ancestor element

Tags: xml, xsd

I know it's certainly possible to define what elements an element can have as direct children.   My problem, however, is that I have an element Foo that cannot contain Bar, while Baz is allowable under Foo, and can also contain Bar.

How do I allow Foo to contain Baz, and Baz to contain Bar, while preventing Foo from ever having Bar as a direct or indirect child?

I'll also gladly take any links to good XSD tutorials or reference.  I've found most reference material to be fairly unapproachable on this subject.

Thanks.

Comment: You have to explain in more detail the schema. If Foo is a direct father of Baz, and Baz is a direct father of Bar. Then Baz can have another direct parent. Is it only one more? For a simple schema I believe it is possible by defining different complexTypes for Baz, one with Bar as the child and one without, depending on the father of Baz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validity of an element can't depend on its ancestors, so you need to define any constraints on the definition of the ancestor element itself. But it's not clear from your description exactly what constraint you want to impose.

For a good guide to XSD I would recommend Priscilla Walmsley's book. Eric van der Vlist is also good; it's worth having both so you get more than one angle on a subject.